# properties file reload on change in server, Spring

Tags: spring, jboss

i am using Spring 4.2.5 and jboss 7 server.

Is it possible to change in application.properties files and make server to reload changed data in application.properties file  automatically on refresh without restarting server?

Please suggest on this. Any idea or steps or api to use anything to move forward.

Regards

Comment: I use tomcat 8. In my spring project in eclipse i have a property file under `src/main/resources`, which will get deployed to **classpath** in webapps. Whenever i make changes to property file, the tomcat server got refreshed.

Dont know about jboss config. But I believe if your property file is in project classpath (or inside project folder in webapps), the server will get refreshed. Please try.

Answer (score 1):

Ideal way would be use spring cloud config 
**@EnableConfigServer**. You will have separate config server pointed all the properties pointed. And a client will be able to access the properties. This allows you to change the properties on the fly in server with out need for any restart.

http://jeroenbellen.ghost.io/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/